# maxHeapify and Heapsort not giving correct output

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, heapsort, max-heap

I am a beginner in competitive coding. I am trying to implement `maxHeapify` and `HeapSort` functions both of which seems to be not working.Trying a lot to debug but couldn't.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    void swap(int *x, int *y)
    {
        int temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
    }
    void maxHeapify(int *arr, int n, int i)
    {
        int largest = i;
        int l = (2 * i);
        int r = (2 * i) + 1;
        while (l <= n && arr[l] > arr[largest])
            largest = l;
        while (r <= n && arr[r] > arr[largest])
            largest = r;
        if (largest != i)
        {
            swap(&arr[largest], &arr[i]);
            maxHeapify(arr, n, largest);
        }
    }
    void heapSort(int *arr, int n)
    {
        for (int i = n / 2; i >= 1; i--)
            maxHeapify(arr, n, i);
        for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            swap(&arr[1], &arr[i]);
            maxHeapify(arr, n, 1);
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        printf("\nEnter size of array\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int *arr = (int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        printf("\nPlease enter array elements\n");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            scanf(" %d", &arr[i]);
        printf("Enter Your choice\n");
        printf("1.maxHeapify\n");
        printf("2.heapSort\n");
        printf("3.Display Heap\n");
        int choice;
        scanf(" %d", &choice);
        while (1)
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                    maxHeapify(arr, n, i);
                break;
            case 2:
                heapSort(arr, n);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\nThe Heap elements are\n");
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                    printf(" %d", arr[i]);
                break;
            default:
                exit(0);
            }
            printf("\nEnter Your choice\n");
            scanf(" %d", &choice);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what should case 1 do?

Comment: @user3365922 It should construct a max heap out of randomly input elements.

Comment: That's how `maxHeapify` called in `heapSort`: `for (int i = n / 2; i >= 1; i--) maxHeapify(arr, n, i);` and that is case 1: `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) maxHeapify(arr, n, i);`. Seems these should be identical, isn't it?

Comment: And why is `while` here: `while (l <= n && arr[l] > arr[largest]) largest = l;`, that can have at most one iteration.

Comment: Since you are storing elements at indexes `1` through `n` and not using `arr[0]`, you need to allocate space for `n+1` elements.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thanks mate. I overlooked that

Comment: @user3365922 changedd it but still heapsort is not working

Comment: MAXHEAPIFY itself is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that your `maxHeapify` is only pushing things down one level. At most. It needs to loop and put the item into the correct place.

Given an array `arr`, an item `i`, and the heap size `n`, the `maxHeapify` function works like this:

```
// find the largest among arr[i], its right child, and its left child
while (i <= n) {
    l = 2*i
    r = l + 1
    largest = i
    if (l > n)
        // left node is beyond the end of the heap
        break
    if (arr[l] > arr[largest])
        largest = l
    if (r <= n && arr[r] > arr[largest])
        largest = r
    if (largest == i)
        // neither child is larger, so done
        break
    // swap node with largest child
    swap(arr, i, largest)
    i = largest
}
```

That's the idea. You'll need to turn it into C code, but that shouldn't pose a problem.

Your case 0 that builds a heap is almost right. It starts at `i = n`. That will work, but it's inefficient. Oddly, you got it right in your heapsort method.

Your `heapSort` is almost correct. You forgot, though, that with each removal from the heap, you need to decrease the size of the heap. The size of the heap isn't `n`, but rather `i`. I changed `n` to `i` in the last call to `maxHeapify`:

```
void heapSort(int *arr, int n)
{
    for (int i = n / 2; i >= 1; i--)
        maxHeapify(arr, n, i);
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        swap(&arr[1], &arr[i]);
        maxHeapify(arr, i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your wonderful and very elaborated answer.